# Linux Boot Console (fbcon) Main Monitor Only

Tags: linux, centos, console, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup to my Linux box and am using fbcon to rotate the console to portrait for each display. I'd like to only have the console show up on the primary display though and leave the second display blank (or to be really fancy, put up a boot graphic on the second display).

Is this possible through lilo.conf boot options?

Comment: Do any of the pertinent [VGA Modes](http://wiki.antlinux.com/pmwiki.php?n=HowTos.VgaModes) work?

Comment: Yes. I have vga=794 (or whatever) in my lilo.conf and it's applied to both monitors.

Comment: You might attempt `vga=771`, which is a more generic (and single-monitor-only) VESA driver.